# An error was raised by libgit2. Folder name longer than 256 chars

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, yeoman

I am using the yeoman nuget package in a visual studio .NET MVC project to generate an angularJS front end.  After installing yeoman and generating an app, I get this error trying to commit to git:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Invalid (Error).
>   Failed to open directory 'C:/my/project/node_modules/super/long/directory'

This is happening because of the dreaded Windows 256 character limit on file/directory names.  How do I fix this so I can commit to git?

Comment: they are adding support for `core.longpaths` here https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3053

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this answer, but it works.  The long paths were for 2 specific grunt node modules that I did not need.  Specifically `grunt-contrib-imagemin` and `grunt-google-cdn`.  So here's what I did:

1. Move those folders out of the node_modules folder to some folder outside of your project.
2. Now you will be able to commit to git, but your grunt build will fail.
3. Remove `cdnify` and `imagemin` from the `Gruntfile.js` to remove those tasks from the build.